# d-link dir-615 H1 keeps boot looping as soon as wifi is enabled?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, openwrt

I have tried various firmware's from stock to ddwrt and openwrt!

Every time I install a stock or ddwrt firmware it just boot loops continuously!
With nothing else plugged in at all, I get orange power light, wifi power lights up twice then lan ports 1 + 3 flash twice and boot loops back to the beginning.

This only happens when Wifi is enabled!

Using openwrt which doesn't enable wifi by default the rest of the router works fine. With latest Openwrt firmware I can connect the Wan port to my existing network and run wired connections through the other 4 ports fine.

As soon as I enable wifi -bam- it boot loops! Only way to get it back again is to hard reset, re flash with original firmware, soft reset, re flash with Openwrt to get back to something I can at least access and get past the boot loop.

I have tried at least 5 of the Dd-wrt firmware's and 3 of the Openwrt firmware's plus 2 stock firmware's. All have the same outcome Original and Dd-wrt firmware's boot loop as soon as they've be written, Openwrt boot loops as soon as wifi is enabled.

I've even tried various wifi settings from Access point to Adhoc, various power settings, various encryption settings, various power levels, etc, etc. Seriously frustrating!

Also if I use Opewrt to find and connect to existing wifi it works as a wifi extender, but I cannot set it up as a wifi access point?

Comment: Try enabling wifi after booting. Are you using the most up-to-date version of the firmware? What specific model are you using?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue if this problem happens with the stock firmware.  You would need to review the logs to determine the reason for the reboot.

Comment: user96931 

It doesn't matter when wifi being enabled happens it immediately boot loops as soon as wifi is enabled!

The model name is in the title - D-Link DIR 615 H1

Currently using the most up to date version of OpenWrt as it is the only firmware I've managed to install that doesn't have wifi enabled by default and therefore doesn't boot loop by default!...

firmware: openwrt-15.05.1-ramips-rt305x-dir-615-h1-squashfs-factory.bin

Comment: Ramhound any idea how to get logs? 
Like I said as soon as wifi is enabled it boot loops. And the only way to get back in is to hard reset and reinstall firmware wiping the logs lol

Comment: It does this from the terminal too? What happens with ifconfig up/down?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart The joys of Win10... I've no idea how to ifconfig lol! But it appears that bash shell doesn't yet allow that command to function from within win10 although the services says it should....

Comment: Scratch all the above lol!
Worked it out. It appears that the power supplies I've been trying are not putting out enough juice...
It says 5v @1.2Amp. I now have it hooked up to a 12v 1.5amp dc power supply and it is working fine!
2 different 5v usb power supplies I was testing and both say 2.5 amp output but as soon as I connect them to this unit it just boot loops as soon as the wifi turns on...
Go figure!!!
Ah how - seems it's fully functional after all :P

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this user can no longer replicate the problem. (User error, using the wrong power adapter)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the very same problem, on the same router. Overnight it stopped working and got into a boot-loop. I checked the power supply and the power rating of the router, those stats matched and the power supply was providing the correct voltage. I had a gut feeling that it might be the power.
I stumbled over this post here an read that Jerry had the same problem and simply switched to 12V and 1A. I did not do anything else and now it works again.

I writing this answer for others to see, because Jerry's comment about the solution is only seen when the comment section is expanded.

Comment: Isn't the DIR-615 a 5V 1a powered unit? - It won't last long on 12v